# Count column values Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, count

SQL:

table name **"videos"**

column name **"views"**

I wanna count all views and showing in User Page.

Example:

Result SQL:

-- views --
3239

2918

2345

1928

32329

---

total views: 42759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a code which worked for me, I've explained the code wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

```
$query = $this->db->select_sum('views')->get('videos')->result();  // gets the sum of data in views column.

$totalViews = $query[0]->views;  // the array returned contains the sum in key {0}

echo $totalViews;  // echo or return the output -- your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the data from the database then use the `array_sum()` function. For example:

```
$builder = $db->table('mytable');
$query = $builder->get()->getResultArray();

$totalViews = array_sum($query['views']);

echo $totalViews;
```